# XUbuntu won't boot up

Tags: xubuntu

A few days ago, I installed XUbuntu onto my Acer Chromebook 14 using the SeaBios Boot Menu by Mr. Chromebox. Today I powered on the device and every time I boot up XUbuntu, the computer completely turns off.

If anyone has a fix please tell me and if you need more details then please ask. Thanks.

Comment: Release details are a start.  If you told it to boot into runlevel 1 were more clues available?   Have you tried booting *live* media and `fsck` your partition(s)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply to this (I forgot my password) but It fixed itself a while ago when I powered it on.